# Enable shim Debian for secureboot

Tags: debian, systemd, grub2, boot-loader, secure-boot

In my Debian system, default efi bootloader is grubx64.efi. I need to use shimx64 for secureboot to work. My machine comes with microsoft keys, so it'll work. I installed the signed shim package and copied the efi files to /boot/efi. I need both shimx64 and grub in same directory because how shim works. But efibootmanager only lists the grub.efi. I can't change the path either. How can I make it default?

PS: I'm using nvme if that helps. Not sata. There was a regex issue which searched for sdX not nvmeXpY, not sure if it's still there.

Comment: No my computers firmware settings is pretty simple. It does have only one option to load a default secureboot key.

Comment: That's not the issue. I would like to boot shimx64. If I do efiboitmgr -v, my current boot options shows \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi. The shim bootloader is signed by Microsoft, so it sould boot.

Comment: Is there an option to set up a "supervisor password" or similar in UEFI? Mine did not show any meaningful options too, until I setup a password. Had to choose "Select a file as trusted" to just add a path for an already signed shim.

Comment: Yes only adding a supervisor password shows  load a default secureboot key option.